# Alternative to Markdown with Color support

Tags: java, android, markdown, markup

I am writing on a Note App (Android and REST API built with PHP/Slim 3). I am wondering if there is something else than Markdown to save notes to a readable and interchangeable format. The problem with Markdown for me is that there is no solution to style texts (e.g. colored text). It is also hard to extend Markdown with custom attributes.

I am already thinking of creating an own data format (or using XML). But this means a lot of work for parsing it. I like the idea of using a standard format to interchange it between client/server and between other applications. But the featureset of Markdown is very limited (by design for sure).

Do you have any tips on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

This question verges on overly-broad, i.e. it may lead to an argument over technologies rather than a "this is the solution" situation.

That being said, here's an answer I think won't be controversial: when you say

> "readable, interchangeable format... solution to style texts... custom attributes"

I think HTML. I don't recommend trying to roll-your-own format, because 1.) you are correct that it will be difficult and 2.) it will be even more difficult to match the feature sets of existing solutions

Comment: I know that this question is unprecise but I didn't know how to ask differently. I already thought of HTML. But there seems to be a big disadvantage using HTML in Android (using Webviews), because of poor performance. To avoid this I need to write my own HTML parser to convert the HTML tags to native android widgets - this is also time-consuming.

Comment: It may not be as bad as you think: I would suggest using an existing HTML parser to get tokens or in-code objects representing the data. This can be limited to exactly the tags, attributes, etc. that **you** need to read and write, i.e. use a `switch` or equivalent and error on anything non-expected, while taking the expected things and converting them into your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up: I like the idea of using HTML instead of Markdown. It is an open standard format and exchangable as well as human-readable. 
The problem I see with all of these solutions: How to write a WYSIWYG-Editor with this in mind? I am already working with Markdown using the Markwon library: https://github.com/noties/Markwon

It is no problem to write Markdown in an Android EditText widget and render it. You can easily convert it back to plaintext (you can save it). It is much more complicated to get a WYSIWYG experience. You have to deal with every User input, writing in a second file or string which contains the Markup while the user just sees the rendered result. The user can edit/delete anything anywhere in the EditText and you have to take care that those changes will affect the Markdown String/File too. I didn't find an easy solution for this.

The easiest way would be to somehow parse the content of the EditText back to Markdown. But there is no getSpannables-method or alike for the EditText widget. I am thinking of looping through the EditText and see what character is there and how it's formatted. But I think this will have disadvantages too, because there are other things like bulleted lists and checkboxes..